# Why airflow throwing exception when task name and task id doesn't match?

Tags: python, airflow

From airflow documentation and reading different sites on the Internet, it is very clear that the task name and task_id is not required to match when creating a task using an operator. For example, I am using the following code:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils import timezone
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from pprint import pprint

default_args = {
    'owner':'me',
    'start_date': timezone.datetime(2019,1,1), 
    'provide_context': True
 }

dag = DAG(
    'etl', # dag_id
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    max_active_runs=2,
    catchup=False
)

def some_function(**context):
    start_time = default_args['start_date']
    print(start_time )

def another_function(**context):
    start_time = default_args['start_date']
    print(start_time )

with dag:
        some_task_name = PythonOperator(
            task_id='some_task_name_id',
            python_callable=some_function,
        )

        another_task_name = PythonOperator(
            task_id='another_task_name_id',
            python_callable=another_function,
        )

        some_task_name >> another_task_name
```

I am testing with the following command:

**airflow test etl_script some_task_name 'args'**

and getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/airflow/.venv/bin/airflow", line 32, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "~/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "~/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 648, in test
    task = dag.get_task(task_id=args.task_id)
  File "~/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 1070, in get_task
    raise AirflowException("Task {task_id} not found".format(task_id=task_id))
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Task some_task_name not found
```

but if I make the task name and id same it works. Why is it happening? I feel like I am missing something but could not figure it out. Can anyone shed some lights?

Environment:
Airflow Version : 1.10.5, Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6

Comment: Does not seem to be able to reproduce your issue. As you mentioned, there is no requirement to match task_name and task_id. Can you post your full DAG file?

Comment: @fuyi added rest of the codes

Comment: I was confused with the "test" command with the task names at the end of dag files. Here is the command layout: "command subcommand dag_id task_id date" from airflow documentation. so the command would look like "airflow test dag_id task_id date".  We have to always use task_id not the name with "test" command. https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html#testing

Comment: @soLegacy you can answer your own question too, if you found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurred not because the task_id and name was different, it was happening because I was using the task name instead of task_id with the **test** command. When testing a dag task from the server command line, the command layout is:

**airflow test dag_id task_id date**

I guess it is better to keep the task name and id same.